# Flutter Riverpod/Provider: Setting an initial state for a stateNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

So I want to have a provider who's initial state will be the a user's location, this is what I have now, is this right?

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/all.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class MapApiState {
  final LocationData userLocation;
  MapApiState({@required this.userLocation});
}

class MapNotifier extends StateNotifier<MapApiState> {
  static Location _location = Location();

  MapNotifier() : super(null) {
    _location.getLocation().then((initialState) =>
        super.state = MapApiState(userLocation: initialState));
  }
}
```

Is this the right approach? How do I now declare the global provider variable for this? The super(null) worries me. But I can't just put "super(_location.getLocation())"

Also, how  should  I then instantiate my global provider variable?

Answer (score 2):

Well it almost depends of how you want to apply it in the lifecycle of your app, you can use `StreamProvider` or `FutureProvider` to get the location and then pass it to your `StateNotifier`

```
final locationProvider = FutureProvider<LocationData>((ref) {
  final Location _location = Location();

  return _location.getLocation();
});

final singleDetailDealProvider = StateNotifierProvider<MapNotifier>((ref) {
  final location = ref.watch(locationProvider);
  return MapNotifier(location.data?.value);
});

class MapNotifier extends StateNotifier<MapApiState> {
  MapNotifier(LocationData location) : super(location);
}
```

That way if you want to use the location somewhere else you can call locationProvider without depending on the state of MapNotifier

Comment: How could I do this without putting the Location() service inside its own provider? The second part of your code looks like something I'd want to use

Comment: The problem with merging all in a single provider is that getLocation is a Future and MapNotifier an StateNotifierProvider, there is no way to await for that future without using a Future provider, if you use ..getLocation as your example it will work but it can make your app junk because it will run the code synchronously

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! This makes sense